# Loss of format due to .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I'm making a .htaccess for my web page, here's the code:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ files.php?row=$1&column=$2 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ $1/1/ 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebpage\.at [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*$
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /imgs/hotlinks.png [L] 

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^imgs/$ [NC]
RewriteRule / - [F]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

The problem is, my images are not showing up in pages with rewritten URLs. Apparently, their routes are also affected by the rewriting. Simply explained: an image located at www.mywebpage.at/imgs/pic1.jpg loads on www.mywebpage.at/files.php?row=first&column=3, but when I try to enter www.mywebpage.at/first/3/ the browser looks for the image in www.mywebpage.at/first/3/imgs/pic1.jpg, and obviously fails to load it.

How can I fix this so that the routes of the images do not change, no matter from where I use them?

Comment: Make the links static. Put your domain in front of every url: `http://website.com/img/pic1.jpg`

Comment: @Rune No doubt that would work, but I was looking for a somewhat more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(imgs)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ files.php?row=$1&column=$2
```

That will rewrite everything except the imgs folder.

Edit: Apologies, misread question.

Make your image paths absolute. E.g. relative path is:

```
imgs/image1.jpg
```

Absolute path is:

```
/imgs/image1.jpg
```

The slash at the beginning tells it to go to the very root of the site and then go to imgs, then image1.jpg.

Comment: That's not the problem. What I need is a way to tell the server to look for the images folder from the root of the domain, not from the rewritten URL

Comment: That worked fine. However, I think I'm going to use a <base> tag, just to avoid going through all my code checking every single link. Thanks!